# AsyncTask's doInBackground not called even when using an executor

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm using an `AsyncTask` and calling it via `executeOnExecutor`, and my `doInBackground` function occasionally fails to get called. Sometimes, simply force-shutting the app from settings will temporarily fix the issue.

Is this a known issue, and is there a fix?

I have tried setting thread priority to max using `Process.setThreadPriority()` with no luck.

Comment: Are you calling `executeOnExecutor` on MainThread?

Comment: It's hard to pinpoint the issue based on the description you provided

Comment: Post the code snippet that you have tried

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: The code is too broad to post @AIK it's a conceptual question, with nothing to do with code.

Comment: Have you tried execute instead of executeOnExecutor?

Comment: execute isn't an option because there's another background thread that indefinitely runs when the app opens.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), parameters);

Comment: I currently use `task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);`

Comment: Let try my recommend.